# unable to get selected segmentedcontrol to highlight on button click

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uisegmentedcontrol

The following method changes the segmented control view from button click but I can't seem to make the selected segmented control item highlighted. I just need show the segmented control index 1 is selected.

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender{

[self addChildViewController:searchPageView];
[self.viewContainer addSubview:searchPageView.view];

[self.segmentedControl setSelectedSegmentIndex:1];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted should work. Try adding a breakpoint to your buttonClicked method to ensure that it is being called when the button is pressed. In the debugger make sure that self.segmentedControl is not nil.